# How to get a list of hoveredPoints in Highcharts v4?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a function to get a list of all hovered points, like for selectedPoints(`getSelectedPoints()`)?
I set the states of some points programmatically with `setState('hover')` and thats why there are more than one points at the same time hovered

here is a simliar jsfiddle for my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xW2MW/122/

if you click on the button and then point with the mouse on the second series, you can see that there are two hovered points(one for each series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can set hover state for many points, but tooltip will be displayed only for one. Finding hover points you can achieve by loop on the all series / points and checking point.state (if it is a hover obiously).

Comment: Nope, you need to preapre you own.